# wide_to_long Valueerror : the id variables need to uniquely identify each row

Tags: python, pandas

I have been using the pd.wide_to_long for quite some time in one of my scripts, however now there has been some underlying data change (in the rows) and it is giving the error: the id variables need to uniquely identify each row

Some articles sugguest using reset_index twice, but that hasnt helped me. (not sure if i used it correctly tho)
Its difficult to the find the change in row content since my last successful run since it has millions of rows.

Data preview:

```
Sector Func   Loc   Accounts ACT_Jan2020 ACT_Feb2020 DP_Jan2021 DP_Feb2021 FY_DP_Jan 2021 FY_DP_Feb 2021 FY20LA_Jan 2021 FY20LA_Feb 2021
Mort      BRO      OI
Mort      BRO      TNCI
Mort      BRO      TOI

df2 = pd.wide_to_long(df,stubnames=["ACT","DP","FY_DP","FY20LA"],
                           i=['Sector Func', 'Loc', 'Accounts'],
                           j="Year_Month", sep="_",suffix=".*").reset_index()

ValueError: the id variables need to uniquely identify each row
```

Expected output:

```
Sector Func   Loc   Accounts Year_month ACT DP FY_DP FY20LA
Mort      BRO      OI        Apr 2020
Mort      BRO      OI        Apr 2021
Mort      BRO      OI        Aug 2020
```

Can you please help me understand what is missing here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for another column passed to `i` parameter for avoid error:

```
df2 = pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(),stubnames=["ACT","DP","FY_DP","FY20LA"],
                       i=['index','Sector Func', 'Loc', 'Accounts'],
                       j="Year_Month", sep="_",suffix=".*").reset_index()
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael, but could you help me how/what happened here

Comment: @asimo - It means there is some duplicated values in `['Sector Func', 'Loc', 'Accounts']`, so failed, because `wide_to_long` nned unique combinations of values in all columns in parameter `i`. So if add `index` (and not duplicated, what is obviously True), get unique combination of `['index','Sector Func', 'Loc', 'Accounts']` and solution working well